# sharing an office add-in to the client

Tags: azure, deployment, publish

I have created an office add-in within visual studio code, I have published it on my Azure Storage Account, and via Centralyzed Deployment I've managed to install it for some users. The problem is that this add-in must be used by some clients, and there is no possibility that they'll use the addin stored in my azure account, and there is no possibility that they will create an account for me on their organization, in order for me to push data directly on their organization's azure account.

So what are the options? I need a solution where i send the office add-in as a zip or something like that, and the company's admin can easily upload that to its Azure account, and the manifest will point to their location. I've seen the possibility of downloading the addin from azure via ftp (without success yet), I imagine if i download that, there might be an option to upload for the client's company admin. Or am I on a wrong track?

many thanks!